# How to make the odata version 7.0 case insensitive

Tags: odata, case, config, case-sensitive

After upgrading to odata version 7(latest right now), the config.EnableCaseInsensitive does not work any more
I tried several work arounds, such as ..
-1. Added a class with CaseInsensitiveResolver specification to the ODataUriResolver singleton
-added a ODataUriHelper class to rewrite the filter

but unfortunately nothing worked
I understand it needs to be case sensitive as per the standard, but 
are there any working solutions to making odata version 7 work with case insensitivity?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now we are using DI to set this configuration, you can do this like:

```
configuration.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata",
        builder =>
            builder.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => edmModel)
                .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>  (ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp =>
                      ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("odata", configuration))
                .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new CaseInsensitiveResolver()));

 public class CaseInsensitiveResolver : ODataUriResolver
 {
   private bool _enableCaseInsensitive;

   public override bool EnableCaseInsensitive
   {
     get { return true; }
     set { _enableCaseInsensitive = value; }
   }
 }
```